# how to get data from 2 diffrent db tables and join together mysql query

Tags: mysql

am working on a project where I need data from two different tables am confused about how to write a query for it, Please help me if possible. MYSQL query

```
table 1 : stagingScriptDB 
table 2 :testBedSuiteMapping
```

I need all data from stagingScriptDB and only tamplate  field from testBedSuiteMapping.
stagingScriptDB  fields
idScriptDB
| scriptName
| platform
| scriptArea
| newArea
| subArea
| module
| component
| minRel
| suiteInfo
| totalTC
| runTime
| status
| scriptSubmitter
| updated_ts
| projectarea
and
testBedSuiteMapping  fields:-
testBedName
| relInfo
| regType
| area
| platform
| suites
| template
| block
| updated_ts
| id

Comment: There are manuals and tutorials a plenty out there on the web. SO is not a tutorial site

Comment: How much [research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and provide your next question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a join of the tables. Do they have a link field?
"testBedSuiteMapping" must have some foreign key.

then it would be like this

```
select stagingscriptdb.*, testbedsuitemapping.yourfield
from stagingscriptdb
inner join testbedsuitemapping on testbedsuitemapping.id = stagingscriptdb.id_stagingscriptdb
```

Comment: 'must have some foreign key.' - NOT so , does need a 'link' field though..